# Are these statements equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Statement 1:

> A sequence $z_n$ is null if $|z_n|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is postive and arbitrarily small. $n>\mu$ where $\mu$ is positive and arbitrarily large.

Statement 2:

> A sequence $z_n$ is null if $\lim_{n->\infty} |z_n|=0$.

I've been going about all my problems assuming the two are equivalent, are they equivalent.

Comment: better way to say statement 1:  There is some large $\mu$ so $n > \mu \implies |z_n| < \epsilon$.

Comment: The first is imprecise. "Arbitrarily small" is vague, and you need to make clear the $\mu$ can depend on $\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Write out the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=0$ to see why.

Comment: Okay, I see. The book is German and uses different symbols if $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ were given I would have gotten it.